# Multiple chartist charts on same page without ID

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

The code below renders only the last chart from `JSON`. I want it to append every chart from `JSON` to a `div` with a class of `reportdiv`.

**Markup**

```
<div class="reportdiv>

</div>
```

**json**

```
  {reportvals:
    {
     labels:["Apple 25%", "Banana 15%", "Mango 10%", "Orange 35%", "Avocado15% "],
     series: [25, 15, 10, 35, 15]
    },
    {
     labels:["Apple 15%", "Banana 25%", "Mango 35%", "Orange 10%", "Avocado15% "],
     series: [15, 25, 35, 10, 15]
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
for (reportindex = 0; reportindex < settings.json.reportvals.length; reportindex++){
  new Chartist.Pie('.reportdiv', {
    labels: settings.json.reportvals[reportindex].labels,
    series: settings.json.reportvals[reportindex].series
  }, options);
}
```

How can I make my code append all charts to the `div`?

I can use an ID selector, but I am not sure count of charts are received from the `JSON`.

Comment: What does your JSON code look like? What's in `settings.json.reportvals`? What does your DOM look like before entering the `for` loop? What does it look like afterwards?

Comment: You increment `portindex` when your variable is infact `reportindex`

Comment: <div class=".reportdiv>
{labels:["Apple 25%", "Banana 15%", "Mango 10%", "Orange 35%", "Avocado15% "]
series: [25, 15, 10, 35, 15]}

Comment: @ AgiHammerthief edited question accordingly